# filtering array removing similar keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array like this one below
I want to remove the keys that are too close to each other, while keeping the one that has greatest value in it.

So for example, in these 3 entries below, I want to keep 165, and unset the other two.

```
[163] => 13
[165] => 15
[166] => 14
```

likewise, in the next pair, I want to keep 172 and remove the others

```
[169] => 17
[170] => 17
[172] => 19
[174] => 14
```

My array looks like this:

```
Array(
    [163] => 13
    [165] => 15
    [166] => 14
    [169] => 17
    [170] => 17
    [172] => 19
    [174] => 14
    [206] => 10
    [216] => 13
    [218] => 15
    [220] => 14
    [228] => 15
    [230] => 18
    [231] => 16
    [234] => 13
    [237] => 10
    [245] => 10
    [248] => 12
    [251] => 15
    [254] => 13
    [256] => 14
    [260] => 15
    [262] => 17
    [264] => 17
    [266] => 16
    [268] => 14
    [271] => 11
)
```

Comment: you need to define "too close to each other"

Comment: What is too close? Does it depend on the value, or also on the position in the array?

Comment: It's not clear what your criteria are. What is "similar"? What is "too close to each other"?

Comment: This sounds like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: "So close, no matter how far"

Answer (score 0):

some things that could be done demonstrated.

```
<?php
$a = array(
    '163' => '13',
    '165' => '15',
    '166' => '14',
    '169' => '17',
    '170' => '17',
    '172' => '19',
    '174' => '14',
    '206' => '10',
    '216' => '13',
    '218' => '15',
    '220' => '14',
    '228' => '15',
    '230' => '18',
    '231' => '16',
    '234' => '13',
    '237' => '10',
    '245' => '10',
    '248' => '12',
    '251' => '15',
    '254' => '13',
    '256' => '14',
    '260' => '15',
    '262' => '17',
    '264' => '17',
    '266' => '16',
    '268' => '14',
    '271' => '11'
);
// arsort( $a ); // sort by value desc
krsort( $a ); // sort by key desc
echo "startet with … ";
print_r( $a );
$d = 0.05; //distance of 5%
$m = false; //flag for first key unset
foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
    if ( $m === false) { // first key will be max one
        $m = $k;
    }
    else if( ($m - $k) < ($d * $m) ) { //comparison for range = $r = $d*$m; //set absolute range for dropping elms
        unset( $a[$k] );//drop an entry
    } else {
        $m = $k;//set new/lower max for comparison
    }
}
echo "endet up with … ";
print_r( $a );
?>
```

if you would have more precise criteria that would help to do the selection you want.

Comment: Hello sir, I'll try to explain more. If you look at the array, you'll see that keys 163, 165, 166 are numbers close to each other, probably 5% difference or so. Likewise, numbers 170, 172, 174 are very close to each other. I want to merge these keys into one key, probably the one that has the highest value... Like value of 172 is 19, which is highest within  that pair.  Thank you :)

Comment: when you look up sorting array you will find `arsort` along other methods on http://php.net/manual/de/array.sorting.php – so you can sort by key as well and use your own rule.

Comment: as in linked doc it is `krsort` for sorting desc by key instead of value. altered the code for that matter …

Comment: @SumitKumar You really need to edit your question to include the criteria for key "closeness" of keys before your question gets shutdown.